# Find coordinates of shapes intersecting

Tags: java, coordinates, shapes, intersection, slick2d

I am trying to find the point where two shapes, (a line and circle), intersect and the coordinate where they do intersect with the end intention of creating a third line to use cosine rule with in order to calculate the angle which the first two lines meet at.

This is using Java with slick2d.
Thanks!

```
public double angleBetweenLines(Line line1, Line line2){

    Circle c = new Circle(self.drawX + 20, self.drawY + 20, line1.getBoundingCircleRadius());
    Line line3 = new Line(/*x Coordinate of where line1 intersects c*/, /*y Coordinate of where line1 intersects c*/, /*x Coordinate of where line2 intersects c*/, /*y Coordinate of where line2 intersects c*/);

}

public void mouseInput(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta){

    Input input = container.getInput();

    int mouseX = input.getMouseX();
    int mouseY = input.getMouseY();

    Line l = new Line(self.drawX + 20, self.drawY + 20, mouseX, mouseY);
    Line n = new Line(800, 0, 800, 900);


    double desiredAngle = angleBetweenLines(l, n);

}
```

The angleBetweenLines method should return the angle between line 1 and 2.
This image shows a diagram of the situation https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8sbq728awqso1l/angle.png?dl=0

Comment: So show what you are trying.

Comment: Attempt to show some code of what you have currently tried @DrDominic. What has/hasn't worked and we can comment guide you from there friend :).

Comment: Please read our How to Ask a question guide (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for ideas on how to improve your question.  The better the question is, the easier it is for everyone to provide assistance.